# Is there a way to do multiple efficient (index-using) finds in one request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection of "events" that have occurred out in the world, where an "event" is a change in the value of some metric that causes us to assign it a different status. For instance, if a widgetCount falls below 10, we might create an "warning" event when that happens, and then if it rises back above 10 we'd log an "ok" event. The event record contains information about where and when the event took place, and what metric changed to trigger the event. My node application often needs to know the most recent event for each metric at a given location, and there may be 15 or so metrics that I'm interested in at once. I'm having difficulty getting the query (or queries) to to retrieve this information to perform well, despite having the right indexes in place.

Let's say an event record looks like this:

```
{
  location: 'Anytown',
  metric: 'widgetCount',
  time: new Date('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  value: 42,
  status: 'ok'
}
```

And the collection has an index on `{location: 1, metric: 1, time: -1}` and also on `{location: 1, time: -1}`.

When I `find()` each location/metric combination individually from node, each query is completely matched to the first index, and only takes 1-5ms to execute in mongo (I know from inspecting profiling in the mongo log), so perhaps 40ms for all metrics at a location. However, the overhead of doing 15 different queries bumps up the total retrieval time *in node* for all metrics at a location to roughly 3s per location, even though they're parallelized in a `Promise.all()`. The individual queries look like this (in this case, I'm looking for the state of things around April 1 at midnight rather than right now):

```
// Repeat this 15 times in a Promise.all(), once for each metric of interest
db.getCollection('events')
.find({
  location: 'Anytown',
  metric: 'widgetCount',
  time: {$lt: new Date('2019-04-01 00:00:00')}
})
.sort({time: -1})
.limit(1)
.toArray()
```

I realized that because all of the finds have some conditions in common (the location and the time frame), I could use an aggregation pipeline, first matching on the common criteria, sorting by time, then doing facets where each facet matches to an individual metric. This does improve the overall performance somewhat by reducing fifteen queries to one -- total retrieval time in node for a location is about 1.5s using this approach. However, the time spent in mongo goes up by an order of magnitude -- to about 400ms -- because the index is only used for the initial `$match` step, then the secondary `$match` within each facet has to be satisfied with a row scan. The facet approach looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
  {$match: {location: 'Anytown', time: {$lt: new Date('2019-04-01 00:00:00')}},
  {$sort: {time: -1}},
  {$facet: {
    widgetCount: [{$match: {metric: 'widgetCount'}}, {limit: 1}],
    // ...
    // repeat for each different metric I'm interested in
    // ...
  }}
]).toArray()
```

What I would like is some way to tell mongo, "do these 15 different finds on this one collection all at once, then give me all the results back in a single object (or array)". In my dream world, I could get the low individual query times of my first approach combined with the low query overhead of my second approach. **Is there a way to do this?** Alternatively, are there ways to reduce the query overhead so the first approach with 15 separate queries performs better?

Note: I also tried doing a variant of the `$facet` approach where `$facet` is the first stage in the pipeline and each facet's `$match` provides all the query criteria, in the hope that mongo might use the index within each facet if the facet's `$match` was the first instruction encountered, but that turned out to be much slower than either of the above approaches because it was done entirely with row scans. tl;dr: Apparently mongo will not use indexes within a facet under any circumstances.

I'm currently on mongodb 3.4 and node 10.14.1, for what it's worth.

Comment: Doing these as separate queries should be fine, but make sure your connection pool is large enough that they can all execute in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyHK, looking into `poolSize` was an interesting idea, but raising it from the default of 5 to 50 doesn't seem to improve performance either locally or in my server environment. Since writing my question, I have noticed that in my server environment (where network latency isn't a concern) the multi-`find()` version is, indeed, about twice as fast as the faceted version (an average of 0.29s per location from node vs. 0.59s) so I will probably go with that but am open to other suggestions!